# Clojure noir: Unable to use images in resources/img

Tags: clojure, compojure, noir

I've been starting trying out noir, though I am now having an annoying problem:

I have a background image stored at `project-folder/resources/public/img/bg.png`. And my css file references it as '/img/bg.png'.

Though, the browser seems unable to load this image.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going wrong?

Comment: how you deploy/run your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img file was corrupted. I was already able to load it on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this problem: another common cause is not having the resources folder on the classpath.